# multirow: Where is my Use of multicolumn Going Wrong?

Tags: tables, multirow, booktabs

I am trying to subdivide heading of a column frequency into morn, noon, eve, night using package multirow. But I am getting error, which I am not able to rectify. Kindly help

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{multirow, booktabs}
    \usepackage{arydshln}
    \setlength{\dashlinedash}{.4pt}
    \setlength{\dashlinegap}{.8pt}
\newcommand{\instructions}{\footnotesize{$\frac{before}{after}$meals/bedtime}}
    \begin{document} 
    \begin{center}
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.75}
    \setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.1pt}
    \begin{tabular}{p{0.5cm}|p{3cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{3cm}|p{2cm}|p{3.5cm}}
    \toprule 
    \multirow {2} {*} {Sr}      & {Drug} & {\multicolumn{4}{c|}{Frequency}}& {Duration} & {Remark}\\ 
                                                        &                   & Morn & Noon & Eve & Night         &                           &                   \\
    \midrule
     1  &      &        &           & \hspace{1cm} days          & \hspace{1cm}{\instructions}  \\ \hdashline
     2  &      &        &           & \hspace{1cm} days          & \hspace{1cm}{\instructions}       \\ \hdashline
     3  &      &        &           & \hspace{1cm} days          & \hspace{1cm}{\instructions}       \\ \hdashline
     4  &      &        &           & \hspace{1cm} days          & \hspace{1cm}{\instructions}     \\ \hdashline
     5  &      &        &           & \hspace{1cm} days          & \hspace{01cm}{\instructions}      \\ \hdashline
     6  &      &        &           & \hspace{1cm} days          &        \\ \hdashline
     7  &      &        &           &                            &        \\  \bottomrule 
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: you have, beside unusual table design, more problems: (i) curly braces around `\multicolum{4}{c|}{...}` had to be removed, (ii) number of declared columns not correspond to number of used columns.

Answer (score 2):

Let extend my comment to an answer. I guess that your table should looks something like this:

[image]

Changes in comparison to your MWE:

- instead `tabular` is used `tabularx`
- number of columns is increased to 9, from them three serves as replacement for `\hspace{...}`
- `\aboverulesep` and `\belowrulesep` is set to zero for better looks of vertical lines
- definition of \instructions is improved

For all this changes are enabled with packages added in preamble: `geometry` for determine page layout, option `showframe` show it, `amsmath` (for `\instructions`), `tabularx` for replacement of `tabular`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow, tabularx}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setlength{\dashlinedash}{.4pt}
\setlength{\dashlinegap}{.8pt}
\newcommand{\instructions}{$\frac{\text{before}}{\text{after}}$ meals/bedtime}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.75}
    \setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.1pt}
    \setlength\aboverulesep{0pt}
    \setlength\belowrulesep{0pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{| l |
                               p{3cm} |
                               X |
                          *{2}{X X |}
                               X l |
                          }
    \toprule
\multirow{2}{*}{Sr}
& Drug  &   \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Frequency}
                                    &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Duration}
                                                    &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Remark} \\
\cdashline{2-9}
&       &   Morn    &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Noon}
                                &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Eve}
                                            &   &   Night           \\
    \midrule
1  &    &  ~        & ~& daily  &  ~& days  & ~ &   \instructions   \\
    \hdashline
2  &    &           &  & daily  &   & days  &   &   \instructions   \\
3  &    &           &  & daily  &   & days  &   &   \instructions   \\
    \hdashline
4  &    &           &  & daily  &   & days  &   &   \instructions   \\
    \hdashline
5  &    &           &  & daily  &   & days  &   &   \instructions   \\
    \hdashline
6  &    &           &  & daily  &   & days  &   &                  \\
    \hdashline
7  &    &           &  &        &   &       &   &                   \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @CarLaTeX, thank you for correction my errors in typing ... now I see, that my MWE wasn't recent (in it were missed invisible characters `~` ). I'm sorry I know only few Italian words ...

Comment: You're welcome! However, it was funny! :):):):)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working version (removing the grouping around `\multicolumn`, correcting the amount of columns used), but you should consider the following points:

- As you can read in the documentation of `booktabs` you should definitely avoid using vertical lines in a table. That just doesn't look nice. If you need those vertical lines there's still the option to use stock LaTeX's `\hline`.
- It's definitely not good to design the last column as it is now, there's too much space. Maybe that should be removed.
- Your row with Morn/Noon etc. did not match any useful definition according to the columns, so I've removed it. Probably you need more columns for that.

[image: bad table]

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{multirow, booktabs}
    \usepackage{arydshln}
    \setlength{\dashlinedash}{.4pt}
    \setlength{\dashlinegap}{.8pt}
\newcommand{\instructions}{\footnotesize{$\frac{before}{after}$meals/bedtime}}
    \begin{document} 
    \begin{center}
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.75}
    \setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.1pt}
    \begin{tabular}{p{0.5cm}|p{3cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{3cm}|p{2cm}|p{3.5cm}}
    \toprule 
    \multirow{2}{*}{Sr} & Drug & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Frequency} & Duration & Remark\\ 
        &      &        &           &                   &\\
    \midrule
     1  &      &        &           & \hspace{1cm} days          & \hspace{1cm}{\instructions}  \\ \hdashline
     2  &      &        &           & \hspace{1cm} days          & \hspace{1cm}{\instructions}       \\ \hdashline
     3  &      &        &           & \hspace{1cm} days          & \hspace{1cm}{\instructions}       \\ \hdashline
     4  &      &        &           & \hspace{1cm} days          & \hspace{1cm}{\instructions}     \\ \hdashline
     5  &      &        &           & \hspace{1cm} days          & \hspace{01cm}{\instructions}      \\ \hdashline
     6  &      &        &           & \hspace{1cm} days          &        \\ \hdashline
     7  &      &        &           &                            &        \\  \bottomrule 
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
    \end{document}
```